# AngularJS form validation and server side control

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, angularjs, authentication

I need to have a form login in a popin, and on submit, a control will be proceed to evaluate if the user is valid.

- if the user is not valid : display an error message
- if the user is valid : continue to a server side validation and authentification

For the moment, I can only check if the user is valid but I don't know how can I proceed to a log in server side.

This is my twig template :

```
<form name="loginForm" class="partial-login" ng-submit="loginCheck()">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" required ng-model="user.email"/>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" required ng-model="user.password"/>
    <input class="button flat small right" type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans() }}"/>
</form>
```

This is my angular code :

```
$scope.loginCheck = function() {
    if($scope.loginForm.$valid) {
        $http({
               methode: "GET",
               url: "/login/check",
               params : {email : $scope.user.email, password : $scope.user.password}
            }).
            success(function(data, {
                if(!data.response) {
                    $scope.error = true;
                }
                else {
                    // how can I send my form to php without AJAX ?
                }
            }).
            error(function() {

            });
    }
    else {
        $scope.error = true;
    }
}
```

So, I want to know in the success in the else condition how can I send my form to the right address in PHP because I need to send my information to PHP because it's a login form and I need to reload the page. AJAX is not my solution.

Thanks !

Comment: really not clear what your issue is

Comment: what @charlietfl says. Also, just out of curiousity, why can't you use an AJAX request with a login form?

Comment: Hi. charlietfl : I just want to log my user and before to send my request I want to validate if my user is ok. I.E : in jQuery we can make a "return false;" if the user is not valid. @Sprottenwels So you think I can log my user with $http.post and reload after my page ? For resume : I just want to send my form to my server in a normal way if my user is valid (it's for reload the page only if I know if my user will be correctly logged)

Comment: And I also need to send hidden input (my form is provided by FOSUserBundle)